# Как добавить параметр к существующему data в ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, opencart2.0

Как добавить к `data` еще 1 параметр `shipping_code`?

Я сделал как ниже, просто добавил к `data +'{shipping_code': shipping_code}`, но в итоге ничего не получилось, уходит объект, а нужно чтобы уходил простой post параметр как и во всех других параметрах в `data`

```js
var shipping_code = $('select[name=\'shipping_method\'] option:selected').text();

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'post',
  data: $('select[name=\'payment_method\'] option:selected,  select[name=\'shipping_method\'] option:selected, select[name=\'order_status_id\'], #tab-total select, #tab-total textarea[name=\'comment\'], #tab-total input[name=\'affiliate_id\']') + '{shipping_code': '+shipping_code+'
}
',
dataType: 'json',
crossDomain: true,
beforeSend: function() {
  $('#button-save').button('loading');
},
complete: function() {
  $('#button-save').button('reset');
},
success: function(json) {
  $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

  if (json['error']) {
    $('#content > .container-fluid').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
  }

  if (json['success']) {
    $('#content > .container-fluid').prepend('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + '  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div><a href="/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Посмотреть заказ</a><br><br><br>');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 'slow');

    // Refresh products, vouchers and totals
    $('#button-refresh').trigger('click');
  }

  if (json['order_id']) {
    $('input[name=\'order_id\']').val(json['order_id']);
  }

  $('#button-save').after('<br><br><a href="/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Посмотреть заказ</a>')

},
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
  alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
}
});
```

Comment: А ошибки  `json` нет? И что у вас в `$('select[name=\'payment_method\'] option:selected,  select[name=\'shipping_method\'] option:selected, select[name=\'order_status_id\'], #tab-total select, #tab-total textarea[name=\'comment\'], #tab-total input[name=\'affiliate_id\']')`. Консоль покажите.

Comment: А до вашего добавления код работал? А то судя по коду уходит jQuery объект.

Comment: да все работало до этого отлично

Comment: Это у меня так перед добавлением  + '{shipping_code': '+shipping_code+'}'

https://ibb.co/Ms5kSf7


А так после

https://ibb.co/0GbYKKv

Comment: то есть те параметры которые передавались до того как я вписал как будто удалились

Вот кстати код мой

https://ibb.co/M1B6Tsg

Comment: Кстати попробовал так: https://ibb.co/8DNxSqJ

мне кажется я на верном пути, но  с синтаксисом накосячил

Comment: Помогиииите! пожалуйста SOOOOS

Comment: @Сергей вы просите помощи, ничего не делаяю Где консоль?

Comment: @doox911  смотрите скрины выше, в консоли ошибок нет, https://ibb.co/dWBvKfX

Comment: @Сергей вечером посмотрю

Comment: @doox911 спасибо, нашел решение, сделал, заработало

Answer (score 0):

Все сделал, пришлось пересобрать данные

сделал так

```
 var payment_method = $('select[name=\'payment_method\'] option:selected').val();

 var payment_code = $('select[name=\'payment_method\'] option:selected').text();

 var order_status_id = $('select[name=\'order_status_id\']').val();

 var comment = $('#input-comment').val();

 var affiliate_id = $('#tab-total input[name=\'affiliate_id\']').val();


 data: 'shipping_method='+shipping_method+'&shipping_code='+shipping_code+'&payment_method='+payment_method+'&payment_code='+payment_code+'&order_status_id='+order_status_id+'&comment='+comment+'&affiliate_id='+affiliate_id,
```